# Why is multiplying an array by a constant changing the array size?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to do some very basic matrix arithmetic but for some reason, even the most basic operation of multiplying an array by a constant is giving weird results. Here is the code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a*3
```

It is returning this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

This makes no sense to me. Why is multiplying an array by a constant changing the dimensions?

Comment: That's not an array; it's a list.

Comment: ok sorry, i was getting confused. Can anyone explain why [[1,2,3]]*3 repeats the array inside this to give [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] ?

Comment: Because (reference semantics aside) it's the same as `[[1,2,3]] + [[1,2,3]] + [[1,2,3]]`.

Comment: Taking reference semantics into account, the resulting list contains 3 references to the single list `[1,2,3]`, rather than a list to 3 distinct copies of the list `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: but surely `[[1,2,3]] + [[1,2,3]] + [[1,2,3]]` would equal `[[1,2,3] + [1,2,3]+[1,2,3]] = [[3,6,9]]` ?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. See my answer. Python does not provide point-wise operations on lists. `[1,2,3] + [1,2,3] == [1,2,3,1,2,3]`.

Comment: I strongly suggest you consult the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial), specifically the [introduction to lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: I'm voting to close this, it's just a matter of basic Python functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how `list.__mul__` is defined; you aren't doing pointwise multiplication, but generalizing list concatenation.

For any list `lst`,

- `lst * 0 == []`
- `lst * n == lst + lst * (n-1)` for `n > 0`

where `+` is list concatenation. If `a` and `b` are lists, `a + b` is the list consisting of all the elements of `a`, followed by all the elements of `b`.

If you want a `numpy` array, as implied by the tag, you have to create one.

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> array([1,2,3]) * 3
array([3, 6, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
a * 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in python there are no arrays but lists. A list can have any type of data such as strings, numbers, dictionaries, etc. That is why when you try a*3 for a list a=[1, 2, 3] means you want to concatenate 'a' list three times.

In order to use arrays you have to import numpy as follows:

```js
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a*3
```